# What's wrong with my code? first letter of each word should capitalized

Tags: javascript

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var str1 = str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  var str2;
  for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
    str2 = str1[i].toLowerCase().replace(str1[i].charAt(0), str1[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase());        
  }
  return str2.join(' '); 
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

What's wrong with my code? **str2.join is not a function**

Comment: Perhaps you should make `str2` an array, and push back new elements in the loop? Instead of assigning a string to it every iteration I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to go about this is to split the string on every space, then set the first letter of each element in the array to the capitalized version of the letter and join it back.

What you are doing is assigning the value of the result to **str2**, having a string type rather than an array, that is why **join** is not working for you.

```
function titleCase(str) {
    const words = str.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}
```

A slightly different variant with some ES6 favor to it:

```
const titleCase = str => {
    const result = [];
    for (const word of str.split(' ')) {
        result.push(word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
    }
    return result.join(' ');
};
```

If you want to ensure space characters such as tabs, newlines etc. work, you can split using your regex or replace all whitespace characters with spaces as a first step, e.g.:

```
const words = str.replace(/\s/g, ' ').split(' ').filter(word => word !== '');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I see my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var str1 = str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  var str2 = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){

    str2[i] = str1[i].replace(str1[i].charAt(0), str1[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase());        
  }
  return str2.join(' '); 
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution to your problem. However, there are many ways to get the same result this is one of them.

```
function capitalize(str) {
  let str2 = str[0].toUpperCase();
  return str.replace(str[0], str2);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the original question that wanted to capitalise every single word's first letter (aka title case).